# Как оспорить решение модератора об удалении ответа?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, удаление-ответов

Речь об [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/607398/mssql-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-io-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8/608699?noredirect=1#comment833834_608699).

> Тормозит работа в 1С(MSSQL).
>
> Помогите разобраться, в каком месте проседает.
>
> 1С и MSSQL на разных серверах.
>
> На сервере БД, в мониторе ресурсов->диск - до 100% активного времени.
>
> К серверу SQL2008R2, диски sas 10k, в raid10, подключены через fiber 6
>   GBit.
>
> В момент нагрузки, в мониторе ресурсов - одна база активно пишет на
>   диск до 16 мб/сек. Всего баз много, самых активных 3-4.
>
> В SQLServer: Memory Manager: Total server memory - 40960000 Target
>   server memory - 40960000
>
> Здесь не понятно, сервер занял всю выделенную ему память и ему не на
>   что больше расчитывать?
>
> SQLServer: Buffer Manager: Pages Write/Sec - 898108755

Опубликовал ответ

> Вопрос больше к 1С-никам, чем к базистам ибо все проблемы, как
>   правило, кроются в специфике взаимодействия 1С с БД (из наблюдений и
>   по словам умудрённых опытом коллег). Соответственно нужен более
>   глубокий анализ окружения проблемы для точного ответа.
>
> Рекомендую пройти [этот нагрузочный тест](http://www.gilev.ru/tpc1cgilv/) для начала и посмотреть на его
>   результаты, возможно что-то прояснится. Так же на [этом сайте](http://www.gilev.ru/) есть
>   другие бесплатные инструменты для анализа, есть и платные. Автор
>   известен, как специалист именно по связке 1C+SQL Server. [Вот ещё](http://www.gilev.ru/systemperfomance/) по
>   теме. Посмотрите [рекомендации по выбору железа](http://infostart.ru/public/154405/). По-возможности
>   дополняйте вопрос, если он не решится

его удалили или преобразовали в комментарий - не понятно, так как комментария нет. Модератор пишет:

> Ответ должен быть полноценным ответом, полностью решающим проблему.

но полностью решить проблему ТС невозможно хотя бы по причине того, что проблема не понятна ему самому - метку 1С к вопросу добавил я. Такой объём текста в комментарии не поместился, поэтому посчитал, что в качестве ответа будет проще.

---

В общем неприятно такие пощёчины получать на ровном месте. Хочу справедливого разбирательства.

Comment: Как оспорить — именно так, написать на Мету.

Comment: @Anatol  Мой ответ к вашему вопросу был удален. Я думаю, теперь вы имеете ясное представление о том, как "оспорить" решение модератора.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow А в чём ваше оспаривание было? Со стороны больше похоже на неадекватное поведение и искробления. Если вы с чем-то несогласны, то напишите об этом вопрос в конструктивной манере. Только больше про действия и обоснования в чём их ошибочность, а не переход на личности и обзывательство.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Удивительно, что за такие "оспаривания" вас не банят.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow То есть если я соглашусь с мнением модератора, то я сразу холуй?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow А можно пример хамства, раз вы называете хамьём модераторов?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Если модератор удаляет совершенно корректный и по существу ответ только потому, что он не совпадает с его мнением, и при этом использует лживый предлог, что, якобы ответ вызовет холивар, чего на этом сайте быть не может, то этот модератор - обыкновенное хамье. Хамью не надо давать власть, так как хамье будет стараться избавляться от всех, кто выше их по интеллекту и профессионализму. Это давно известный жизненный факт.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Короче говоря, модераторы вас глупей и из зависти удаляют ваши ответы?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow А вы знаете, что здесь по правилам вообще не должно быть ответов-мнений? Они здесь не приветствуются, они чаще неуместны. Вы же 100к на enSO получили давая людям факты, а не делясь своим мнением, верно?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov В этом случае вопрос должен быть закрыт, или все ответы должны быть удалены, так как мой ответ ничем не отличается по этому критерию от других ответов. Чтобы вы ориентировались, кого вы собираетесь просвещать, то я вам советую для начала заглянуть в мой профайл и посмотреть мою репутацию не на ru.SO, а на самом SO. Заодно сравните ее со своей репутацией.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Ваше поведение со стороны выглядит некорректным и нелогичным. И когда вам на это указываешь, вам почему-то хочется показать, какой вы "интеллектуал и профессионал", а вокруг вас собрались одни неучи и быдло, и ещё вам почему-то надо показать свои достижения и подчеркнуть это. Даже если вы обгоните Джона Скита по репутации и будете лучшим знатоком C++ в мире, это не даст вам права кого-либо оскорблять.

Comment: Забавно, что вопрос давно уже удален, а драма об удаленном ответе все длится...

Comment: @PavelMayorov вопрос-то удалён, а рана - она осталась

Answer (score 18):

Я когда-то именно на похожем примере хорошо осознал, что не стоит бросаться отвечать на плохо сформулированные вопросы, лучше попробовать уточнить вопрос, и если получилось -- тогда уже отвечать.

А если не получилось -- то и не стоит даже браться. Вы же сами пишете: "решить проблему невозможно", то есть вы понимаете, что ответы заранее БУДУТ ПЛОХИМИ.

А плохой ответ -- это как раз тот самый риск удаления: либо за краткость (это не ответ, это лишь комментарий), либо за ссылку (они могут измениться, либо полностью сайт канет в лету) и так далее.

Лично у меня нет доступа ко всем инструментам модерирования (не могу видеть удалённые сообщения - и посмотреть, что конкретно в Вашем было написано), но я скажу так.

Даже если в данном конкретном случае окажется, что сообщение вернут (я сомневаюсь в этом, так как решение о закрытии принимается пятью голосами, а не одним -- это как раз несколько страхует от единоличных ошибок), то попробуйте понять именно общий принцип:

> Не стоит торопиться отвечать на плохо заданные вопросы.

А плохо заданный вопрос ведёт к плохо сформулированному ответу. Есть даже такая расхожая фраза о том, что хорошо заданный вопрос -- это добрая половина ответа. Это реально тесно связанные вещи.

И если вы чувствуете обиду именно за то, что с вами поступили несправедливо: попробуйте посмотреть не только на свой конкретный шаг ("я очень хотел помочь человеку, давая ответ -- ЗА ЧТО МЕНЯ??"), но и на свой предыдущий шаг (попытка ответа на плохой вопрос). Будьте дальновидны:

> если ты очутилась в подземном переходе ночью наедине с бандой
>   гопников, то ошибку ты допустила несколько раньше

Answer (score 10):

> полностью решить проблему ТС невозможно хотя бы по причине того, что проблема не понятна ему самому

Да, совершенно верно.

Мне кажется, вы просто дали ответ на вопрос из серии «угадайте, что у меня в кармане». Чтобы объективно утверждать, что именно создаёт нагрузку на I/O, нужно получить доступ к системе и заняться её профилированием. На такой вопрос нельзя дать исчерпывающий ответ, можно только накидать уточняющих вопросов или ссылок по теме. Крайне редко случается, что автор ответа на подобный вопрос проявляет чудеса телепатии, основанной на экспертных знаниях, и точно угадывает проблему.

Вполне возможно, что данные вами ссылки приблизят автора вопроса к решению проблемы. Но они не являются ответом, а кроме них в ответе ничего нет. Здесь так принято: если у вас есть только ссылки, опубликуйте их в комментариях. Ответ был удалён именно по этой причине. То, что часть ссылок ведёт на платные услуги — вторично.

Думаю, что такая формулировка вопроса была бы корректнее: «Как определить источник нагрузки на disk i/o в связке 1C + MSSQL». В ответах было бы что-нибудь такое:

1. Провести нагрузочные тесты с запросами вида A, B, C, и профилем нагрузки P, при этом мониторить параметры X, Y, Z на таких-то машинах. В качестве примера можно использовать эти тесты (ссылка).
2. Результаты интерпретировать следующим образом: (подробное объяснение).
3. Провести нагрузочные тесты с профилем нагрузки P2, таким образом определить максимальную нагрузку на диск (она будет существенно меньше, чем максимальная скорость последовательной записи на диск). Сделать вывод о том, является ли текущая нагрузка узким местом системы и нужно ли её вообще оптимизировать.
4. Попробовать поменять конфигурацию (код прямо в ответе), прогнать те же тесты с другой конфигурацией, сравнить результаты. Подробнее о конфигурации можно почитать (ссылка).
5. Попробовать ещё что-то (оптимизировать запросы, масштабировать железо, поставить SSD), прогнать тесты, и т.д. в цикле до достижения желаемого результата.

Comment: Согласен, но где комментарий, в который должно было быть преобразовано сообщение?

Comment: А что касается _только ссылки_ и прочее, то изначально хотел написать в комментарии, но потом понял, что формат не тот. Тупо в один коммент не вместилось вот и не стал нагромождать.

Comment: Ну и кажется не логичным, что модератор удалил мой ответ и при этом не заметил плохого качества вопроса, пытаясь даже влезть в проблему, в которой он очевидно не компетентен.

Comment: @Anatol сорри, не могу сейчас ответить развернуто. У комментариев есть лимит по длине и ограничения по оформлению. Ваш ответ после преобразования в коммент выглядел ужасно (не по вашей вине). Творчески перерабатывать каждый конвертируемый ответ у модератора нет.

Comment: @Anatol в проблеме оптимизации и мониторинга SQL я как раз вполне компетенен - именно поэтому я попытался узнать у автора вопроса подробности в комментариях. А не стал давать общий ответ "докиньте памяти, купите диск побыстрее".

Comment: @Pasha в этом я Вашу компетенцию не оспариваю, но там 1С присутствует. А Вы об этом не заикнулись даже, хотя это ключевой момент.

Comment: @Anatol не ключевой. у автора 1c и mssql на разных серверах. что сводит ситуацию к "есть сервер с (вроде бы) хорошим , на нем стоит база какого-то приложения, которая (вроде бы) пишет на диск (не слишком активно). есть общие подходы к мониторингу и оптимизации таких ситуаций. к сожалению, для их применения нужно  хорошо понимать как работает SQL Server, как он выделяет память, когда и как он пишет на диск, когда он читает с диска. Это нельзя вместить в один ответ.

Comment: @Anatol смотрите, по правилам - я должен был закрыть вопрос сразу же как увидел. И вы и я понимаем, что ответа на такой вопрос может быть всего два - "станьте DBA" или "наймите DBA". Но модераторы избегают закрывать вопросы в один клик  (по разным причинам). Это не означает, что вопрос понравился (или не понравился) лично мне. Но все советы (особенно те, которые скорее всего приведут топикастера к найму платного специалиста) - должны быть в комментариях.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ох уж эти QA... fixed!

Comment: @NickVolynkin мне проще не ставить точки...

Comment: @Pasha вполне понятна мотивация и прочее, однако всё же считаю такую меру чрезмерной, простите за тавтологию. Вопросов и, тем более, ответов по этой тематике на со нет. Вероятно это принесло бы кому-нибудь пользу, к тому же сейчас сам изучаю эту специфику и, возможно, удалось бы дополнить ответ.

Comment: @Anatol `но полностью решить проблему ТС невозможно...` - [не на все вопросы стоит отвечать. Уберегите себя от разочарования и не отвечайте на вопросы, которые: **непонятны или не содержат конкретных подробностей, что не позволяет однозначно определить проблему; требуют слишком много наводящей информации для полного ответа;**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ваше желание помочь весьма похвально, но правила сообщества были написаны не просто так.